# Service reference not asking for authentication details

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, soap, wsdl

I have created WSDL file and when I add service reference in VisualStudio I can use it to fetch the data. However what I want to achieve is when I add service reference it should ask me for credentials by an authentication windows popping up.

What do I need to add to my WSDL file?

I am attaching link to my WSDL file.

Any help will be appreciated.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/654fcddcdee2f9848500

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve this when you add a local Wsdl file in the IDE as a service reference to your project.

Unless you place the file on a network file share which will popup and ask for credentials.

Another way would be to host the Wsdl via an IIS web service with basic or windows authentication.

According to your comment you are accessing the WSDL using a URL. The question is this a WCF service endpoint? If so (MEX) meta data exchange is used to provide you the Wsdl. You can change the MEX endpoint to use https **mexHttpsBinding**. See following link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa967391(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean. I am storing my WSDL file on the remote server and calling it using URL. It still does not ask me for credentials.

Comment: Your question is a file and not a URL. I have added to my answer to make it secure